# What to mix 会 and 没有 to say "We won't have any problems."?

Tags: word

I'm now chating with a host over AirBnB. She seems to NOT speak English, so she replyed to me the following:

> 你好，我不会英语，你介意吗

So I tried to reply the following:

> 你好。我会看得懂中文少一点，可是我不会说。如果我们用信息，我们会没有问题。

However, I now wonder if the last sentence is correct or not. Specifially, I think there are some expressions occurred on me:

> 我们会没有问题
>
> 我们不会有问题
>
> 我们会没问题

Is the sentence I used correct? Or is there a better expression here?

---

*By the way is 我不会英语 the correct in grammar or does she just omit it since it is obvious in context?*

Comment: we won't have any problems: 我们不会有问题的, for confirmation try jukuu 
 
also  it should be  我不会说英语，会 is an aux. or modal v.(助动词／能愿动词）and as in E should be followed by a v. (cf. e.g.＂外国人实用汉语语法＂帮助动词表示需要、可能或愿望叫助动词。

Comment: 会 besides being a modal verb also is a full-fledged verb meaning (8) 懂得 [know]。 如: 他会英文; 他会做思想工作, thus  comment#1 must be corrected accordingly (see answer below)

Comment: It is much better to make use of a translator app. Or you can make use of an online translator.
www.tokohow.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the sentence I used correct? Or is there a better expression here?

1.*我们会没有问题* - 我们 (we) | 会 (will) | 没有 (not have) | 问题 (problem)

2.*我们不会有问题* - 我们 (we) | 不会 (will not) | 有 (have) | 问题 (problem)

*我们会没问题* (just #1 omitted 有)

Both #1 and #2 are correct.

- 没有 (not have) acts on the noun "问题 "(problem)
- 不会 (will not) modify the verb "有" (have)

> By the way is 我不会英语  correct in grammar or does she just omit it since it is obvious in context?

- 我不会英语 means " I don't know English" (don't understand, can't speak, read or write)  or it is "我不会說英语" but omitted the verb "說"
- 我不会說英语 means " I can't speak English"

我不会英语 on its own is grammatically correct. Since she understood what you wrote in English, she was actually saying "我不会說英语" but omitted the verb "說"

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Between #1 and #2, which seems more natural for a native?

Comment: I like 2.我们不会有问题 more

Comment: 会＋verb，不会＋verb is often followed by 的 in the sense of （un）likelihood (in the future)（as in comment #1)，bkrs：不会有好下场的 will come to no good end 不会坐视的 not sit back looking on， jukuu：不会的，维纳斯不会生气的，as far as 不会有问题 is concerned jukuu has many examples both w/o 的 and w 的。

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence has already expressed the basic meaning, so all of them sound ok to me, speaking of a more strict grammar, it's better to add a "的" after each sentence: 我们会没问题 -> 我们会没问题的, as @user6065 already pointed out.

But to sound more nature, I might make two changes:

1. Turn it into an impersonal sentence: 会没事的/是没有问题的（the person 我们 removed）, which can be translated as "It will be ok/fine".
2. Further change, adding some mood to emphasize uncertainty, thus it becomes: 应该会没事的/应该是没有问题的, which can be translated as "It should be ok/fine".

Answer (score -1):

for this conversation it's understandable but a little unnatural.
much better version:
如果我们用信息的话，交流应该没问题=>
如果用信息的话，交流应该没问题=>
用信息的话，交流应该没问题=>
用信息的话，应该没问题。